# IBAction for a standard button doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uibutton, ibaction

It's basic and should work out of the box, so I don't have any clue why it doesn't . I tried to remove link to IBAction and rewritten it again - the Log doesn't show that it was clicked. Weird.

[image]

here's the code :

```
@IBAction func onManClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("onManClicked")
    person.gender = 1
    genderUpdate()

}
```

The `NSLog` part never triggered.
So, none of the four buttons I have in this `ViewController` respond.
Where the problem could be?

This is how I add this whole view - I think this is the problem.

```
    let vc = PersonalDialog(nibName :"PersonalDialog", bundle: nil, section: section, position: position, person: Person())
    vc.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    parentVC.view.addSubview(vc.view)
```

I'm new to iOS developement, I don't know hot to do it right - I understand now that I added a subview but didn't add the controller for it. Probably.However, it does call the `viewDidAppear` method

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking if button interaction is enabled nor its parent view? 
Had it been overlapped by some object or other views?

I experienced this before and I just checked all this and it somewhat fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I tried to remove link to IBAction and rewritten it again

So... Try deleting the connection in Interface Builder and then reconnect (you've probably already done that)

Another thing to look out for.

If I, in Swift 3, create a method like this:

```
    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("hello")
    }
```

and then try to connect to that then the connection looks like this

[image]

Notice the "with sender" part, which I didn't add but which is a part of the new Swift 3 parameter naming.

To avoid that, I have to rename my method to this:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("hello")
}
```

(notice the `_` before sender)

And if I then reconnect:

[image]

things look as expected. Maybe that is what has bitten you too? Interface builder looking for an `@IBAction` called `onManClickedWithSender` and you defining an `@IBAction` called `onManClicked`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes, I deleted references from IB as well. You can look at the picture, it is calling the onManClicked method as in the code it is also onManClicked method. Not any of the 4 button clicks works. I edited my post to show how this view is added. May be this is the problem? I'm new to iOS and swift.

Comment: Could you try renaming it to `onManClicked(_ sender: AnyObject)` (notice the _)

Comment: yes and it shows a warning "Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'sender' has no keyword argument name. Can you plz look at the end of my edited post - may be the problem is there?

Comment: Hmmmm...are you using Swift 2 or Swift 3

Comment: swift 2. I don't want to rewrite the whole project and learn all new features, I want to just finish it and then leard swift 3

Comment: ah...that explains the `_` mystery. I'm terribly sorry but I don't have the solution then :(

Comment: may this be the way that I add subview ? Can you plz look at the end of my question? May be I add this view wrong way?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. I mean, you say that `viewDidAppear` is invoked so it seems that the ViewController and View is wired fine...its "just" the `@IBAction`s that are not getting called.